# CECILIA 5 start problems in Win 10

Tags: audio

When I want to start Cecilia 5, Paint program starts instead. In win 7 I never had this problem.
Thanks for any solution to this headache.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this would be better suited to a general computer issues stack, such as [Superuser](https://superuser.com/)